# Call ASP.MVC action method from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call the controller action method from the jQuery code, but somehow it is not working. Following is the code from javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#sendOTPSubmit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Controllers/RegisterSurfaceController/SendOTP',
            success: function(data) { 
                alert(data); 
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function(content) { 
                    alert('cannot find resource');     
                },
                500: function(content) { 
                    alert('internal server error'); 
                }
            },    
            error: function(req, status, errorObj) {
                // handle status === "timeout"
                // handle other errors
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendOTP()
{            
    CardHolder user = new CardHolder();
    return Json("");
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> http://localhost:49289/Controllers/RegisterSurfaceController/SendOTP 
>   404 (Not Found)

Comment: $.ajax({
                                url: 'Controllers/RegisterSurfaceController/SendOTP', type: "POST",

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you have the `[HttpPost]` attribute on your action, so you need to add `type: 'POST'` to your `$.ajax` options.

Also, unless you've defined an Area named 'Controllers' you shouldn't need that directory in the URL, and you don't need the 'Controller' suffix either. Try just: `url: '/RegisterSurface/SendOTP',`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'RegisterSurface/SendOTP',
    success: function (data) { alert(data); },
    statusCode: {
        404: function (content) { alert('cannot find resource'); },
        500: function (content) { alert('internal server error'); }
    },
    error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
        // handle status === "timeout"
        // handle other errors
    }        
});
```

Also note that if this code above can be run within scope of Razor, then you can use the `Url.Action` helper to generate the URL for you:

```
url: '@Url.Action("SendOTP", "RegisterSurface")',
```

Comment: How do i send the data to the function ?

Comment: You can use the `data` property. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more details